# WSO2 Business Activity Monitor supported payment gateway

Tags: wso2, payment-gateway, wso2-bam

I have configured APIs via the WSO2 API Manager and connected the API Manager to the Business Activity Monitor. I now need to charge for API usage.

Does WSO2 Business Activity Monitor support any payment gateway out-of-the-box? Is there any reference manual or use case about connecting BAM to a payment gateway?

If BAM doesn't support processing payment via integration with 3rd party payment gateways, what should be the best practice to process payments? (e.g. like [StratosLive does](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/08/metering-throttling-billing-stratoslive)?)

I can't seem to find any guide about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [1] for more details for billing and metering. In BAM there is no way to connecting to a payment gateway.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring%2C+Statistics+and++Billing

Comment: Thanks! However the link you sent doesn't provide many details and is mostly about integrating with the BAM (hence my question). Can you be a bit more specific?